# How to handle iPhone X bottom gap when laying out UIViewController

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios11, iphone-x

What is the correct approach for a UIViewController to handle the bottom gap where the home slider is on the iPhone X, ie how should it be laid out?

Answer (score 1):

The [iPhone X Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x) sate that when designing for iPhone X, you must ensure that layouts fill the screen and aren't obscured by the device's rounded corners, sensor housing, or the indicator for accessing the Home screen. So as long as your view is pinned to the top and bottom layout guides you should be good to go.

Check out [Designing for iPhone X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/801/) and [Building Apps for iPhone X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/201) from this fall. They're only 12 mins each, definitely worth watching!